# DRF view returns Invalid username/password with @permission_classes((AllowAny, ))

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I have this method-like api view with AllowAny as permisson class decorator:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
```

But when I reach with the browser to the url it renders the DRF api template with a 403

```
HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Invalid username/password."
}
```

What I am missing? I dont need to specify a setting `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` if I am forcing one through the decorator right?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is you have the session authentication configured but it fails authentication. One thing to know being the session authentication will lead to 403 instead of 401 because session authentication is not compatible with 401 by design: it can not process WWW-Authenticate header.

Comment: What do you mean with session authentication? django or DRF configuration?